# AngularJS Undefined Variables When Trying To Update View From Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I am new to AngularJS and am trying to rewrite my webpage in the "angular way" instead of using jquery but I am running into some problems with my understanding.

I have my HTML like so:

```
<body style="padding-top: 0px;" data-spy="scroll" ng-app="SummerMill">
    <section id="intro" class="main style1 dark">

        <!-- Header -->            
        <header ng-controller="MainController" id="header">

            <!-- Logo -->
            <h1 id="logo">Summer Mill</h1>

            <a ng-mouseover="locations()"
                style="color:black;text-decoration:initial;"
                id="logoii"
                href="http://localhost/locations">Locations</a>

            <!-- Nav -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li ng-repeat="headerLink in headerLinks"><a ng-init="content=headerLink.text" href="#{{content}}">{{content}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Then my controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.headerLinks = [ 
        { 
            text: 'Intro', 
            alternativeText: 'Arlington'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Wholesale', 
            alternativeText: 'New York'
        }
    ];

    $scope.locations = function() {
        content = headerLinks.alternativeText;
    }
}]);
```

So basically, on hover, I want the `<li>` content to change. I know the hover event is being fired, and correctly so. The error I get is that **ReferenceError: headerLinks is not defined** which is odd to me because it is in the controller itself, so I tried `content = $scope.headerLinks.alternativeText;` and that stopped the error but I guess `content` in the controller is not the same as `content` in `ng-init`.

What is the right way to do this? Perhaps I am thinking of this the wrong way.

Comment: first: you does not have `headerLinks` you have `$scope.headerLinks`, second: this variable is array - not an object as you think so it does not have `alternativeText` property

Comment: $scope.headerLinks.alternativeText

Comment: Do you need this content ng-init="content=headerLink.text" in controller ?

Comment: can you explain what you realy need?

Comment: I figured out that it is `$scope.headerLinks` but that didn't solve the problem, which is that `content` in the controller doesn't match `content` in `ng-init`.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper, sure, because `ng-repeat` create own scope, and `ng-init` define `content` inside it

Comment: @Grundy I need the `<li>` content to change from the `text` to the `alternativeText` on hover.

Comment: headerLinks is an array, only its elements have the property `alternativeText`. You should know the index of the element and then you can use `$scope.headerLinks[index].alternativeText`

Comment: where you want get `alternativeText`? it need same for all li?

Comment: @Grundy I need it to repeat just like the `text` repeats right now with `ng-repeat`. Basically I want it as if, on hover, it changed from `content=headerLink.text` to `content=headerLink.alternativeText`

Comment: @SummerDeveloper as you can see, in snippets i not use your `locations` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case better a bit simplify your code like, for example use `ng-if` and flag `isOver`

```js
angular.module('app',[])
       .controller('MainController',function($scope){
  
   $scope.headerLinks = [ 
        { 
            text: 'Intro', 
            alternativeText: 'Arlington'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Wholesale', 
            alternativeText: 'New York'
        }
    ];
$scope.locations = function() {
    content = headerLinks.alternativeText;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->            
<header ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController" id="header">

        <!-- Logo -->
  
        <h1 id="logo">Summer Mill</h1>
        <a ng-mouseover="isOver=true" ng-mouseout="isOver=false"
                style="color:black;text-decoration:initial;"
                id="logoii"
                href="http://localhost/locations">Locations</a>

        <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="headerLink in headerLinks">
                          <a ng-if="!isOver" href="#{{headerLink.text}}">{{headerLink.text}}</a>
                          <a ng-if="isOver" href="#{{headerLink.alternativeText}}">{{headerLink.alternativeText}}</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

</header>
```

also you can you ternary operator instead `ng-if` like this

```js
angular.module('app',[])
       .controller('MainController',function($scope){
  
   $scope.headerLinks = [ 
        { 
            text: 'Intro', 
            alternativeText: 'Arlington'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Wholesale', 
            alternativeText: 'New York'
        }
    ];
$scope.locations = function() {
    content = headerLinks.alternativeText;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->            
<header ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController" id="header">

        <!-- Logo -->
  
        <h1 id="logo">Summer Mill</h1>
        <a ng-mouseover="isOver=true" ng-mouseout="isOver=false"
                style="color:black;text-decoration:initial;"
                id="logoii"
                href="http://localhost/locations">Locations</a>

        <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="headerLink in headerLinks">
                          <a href="#{{!isOver ? headerLink.text : headerLink.alternativeText}}">{{!isOver ? headerLink.text : headerLink.alternativeText}}</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

</header>
```

or even without condition like

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.currentText = 'text';
    $scope.headerLinks = [{
      text: 'Intro',
      alternativeText: 'Arlington'
    }, {
      text: 'Wholesale',
      alternativeText: 'New York'
    }];
    $scope.locations = function() {
      content = headerLinks.alternativeText;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->
<header ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController" id="header">

  <!-- Logo -->

  <h1 id="logo">Summer Mill</h1>
  <a ng-mouseover="currentText='alternativeText'" ng-mouseout="currentText='text'" style="color:black;text-decoration:initial;" id="logoii" href="http://localhost/locations">Locations</a>

  <!-- Nav -->
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ng-repeat="headerLink in headerLinks">
        <a href="#{{headerLink[currentText]}}">{{headerLink[currentText]}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```